# Passing parameters into a ASP.Net Button control when clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button

I have an asp button (the code is below). I have the event handler working, but I want to pass a string (which is the result of a javascript function) into the event handler function. Is there a way to do that?

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1"  OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Run" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the way you would do this is to have you javascript modify an input control so that the value will be posted back with the `Button` click.  If you want the user to visually not be able see the data that your javascript is modifying to post back then you can write it to a `HiddenField`.

You can use the `OnClientClick` to setup the javascript to run before the postback happens to ensure your modified value is put into the input control.  Eg:

```
<asp:Button ID="yourButton" runat="server" Text="Click Me!"
    OnClientClick="YourFunctionToAddStringToControl(); return true;"
    OnClick="yourButton_Click" />
```

So you just need to swap the call to `YourFunctionToAddStringToControl` with your modified javascript function that is writing the value to a `HiddenField` or another input control.  Then update your server side click handler to access the field.

Side Note:  When using javascript to write to server side controls such as `HiddenField`, don't forget to use `<%= yourHiddenField.ClientID %>` to get the correct control name.

Answer (score 2):

Not in the way you're asking.. However...

You CAN add an ASP:HiddenField, and use Javascript to modify the value of the HiddenField to be your string.  Then you can access this in your Button Click event.

An example can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/ajax/pass-javascript-variable-server-side.aspx).

Comment: is there a way to run the javascript function when the button is pressed?